# How to transfer data from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, database, t-sql

The orders table is the sales invoice information.

Transferring this information from SQL Server to Excel is possible with a query.

There is a data transfer wizard method to transfer in the

data, but I have to do it with C# code or T-SQL query.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to transfer the information I have in the SQL server query to an Excel file

Comment: In Excel under the Data menu item choose Get Data/From Database/From SQL Server Database, and follow the prompts.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with C# or T-SQL commands?

Comment: I used SSIS it for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have to make it with T-SQL or C#?

You can make with SSIS package and call that from C# or T-SQL.

If that is possible, I suggest trying it.